# Using PHP to Create a CloudKit Location Object (BYTES) for use with cURL

Tags: php, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

I'm attempting to use the server-to-server key in CloudKit to submit records to the public database.  The cURL submission looks something like this:

```
{"operations":[{"record":{"recordName":"289342E3-AA19-6AAF-8CCF-38B72A686364","recordType":"XXX","fields":{"accountGuid":{"value":"
750f224a-7e0d-45b4-946b-f687672e383f"},"accountEmail":{"value":"
email@domain.com"},entityName":{"value":"Report"},"CD_latitude":{"value":38.8977},"CD_longitude":{"value":77.0365},"CD_location":{"value":{"latitude":38.8977,"longitude":77.0365}},"reportDate":{"value":1685788455000}}},"operationType":"create"}]}
```

The location object used to be a combination of latitude and longitude, but it appears to be a BYTES object in CloudKit now.  If I run a query to return a BYTES (location) object, I get an encoded string:

```
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
```

It appears to be a type of base64 encoding, but I can't figure out how to decode it into an object I can read in PHP and vice versa.